# Magento 2 - How to change htmlClass, htmlId attributes by referenceContainer or another way?

Tags: magento, magento2

[In magento 2 Frontend developer guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html#info), I have read that :

> Certain attributes, like htmlClass, htmlId, label attributes can be
>   changed in extending layouts

I want to change htmlClass of the container defined in 1column.xml. Could you tell me how to do it by referenceContainer or another way ?

I used : (both html_class & htmlClass)

```
<arguments>
            <argument name="html_class" xsi:type="string">sm-page-header</argument>
</arguments>
```

but not affected

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

If a container is declared in xml with the following code:

```
<container name="my.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="old-class">
    <...>
</container>
```

You can simply override the css-class by placing the following code somewhere in your extending layout files:

```
<referenceContainer name="my.container" htmlClass="new-class" />
```

Comment: I guess htmlClass is not used with `<referenceContainer>` https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html#fedg_layout_xml-instruc_ex_ref

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED: Bellow does NOT work;**

```
<referenceContainer name="my.name">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="html_tag" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[]]</argument>
        <argument name="html_class" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[]]</argument>
        <argument name="html_id" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[]]</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: yep, does not work.. but it was supposed to be the new Magento 2 guidelines for overriding arguments, so you earned a +1

Answer (score 0):

For changing or adding new class/id you can use `htmlClass` and `htmlId` attributes in `container` (child of referenceContainer) instead using of `referenceContainer`.

**Example:**

`1column.xml` file path for custom theme
`app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Theme/page_layout/1column.xml`

```
<container name="footer-container" as="footer" before="before.body.end" htmlClass="page-footer another-class" htmlId="test-id" label="Page Footer Container" htmlTag="footer" />
```

for details please take a look in this built-in `1column.xml` file.

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/1column.xml
```